# Splunk rex Search - Unable to tabulate because of NULL

Tags: search, null, splunk, rex

I want to extract "TimesAccesed" from the message field.

```
Message: PublicDomainAPI.SaveAsync: progresses = [{"UserGuid":"0a062514-def3-4ae5-9092-asd12easd","CourseId":"c71f6538-e379-447e-aaf3-asd1dasd","Status":"InProgress","UserScore":1,"TotalTime":"0:23:45","TimesAccessed":null,"CompletionDate":null,"LastTimeAccessed":"2022-07-23T09:59:12.191+00:00","SuccessStatus":"Pass","Bookmark":"en","SuspendData":null,"Progress":null,"RegistrationDate":"2022-07-23T09:59:12.191+00:00","RegistrationNumber":1}], total: 1
```

I used `| rex field=Message "\"TimesAccessed\"\:\"(?<TimesAccessed>[^\"]+)"`

But I am not getting tabulated results because my data has NULL.
The same works for other fields like

```
| rex field=Message "\"TotalTime\"\:\"(?<TotalTime>[^\"]+)" 
| rex field=Message "\"CourseId\"\:\"(?<CourseId>[^\"]+)"
```

Comment: Please share the entire SPL.  Splunk should have no problem displaying "null".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking your regex on regex101 shows that it fails - you're looking to match a literal `"`, but it's not there for your "`null`" value

This [regular expression](https://regex101.com/r/tQcyKw/1) is both simpler to read, and pulls what you're looking for (without the extraneous comma):

```
| rex field=Message "TimesAccessed[[:punct:]]+(?<TimesAccessed>[^\",]+)"
```

Use the `[[:punct:]]` character class to match any punctuation between the text you're trying to match

Comment: A `rex` command that fails to match will create a field with a null value.  null values can be displayed by `table`, but tend to break `stats`.  If we know more about the search we can better suggest fixes, but correcting the regex is the place to start.

Comment: @RichG - the sample data show a string literal of `null`

Comment: Yes, it does, but the given regex fails to find it so the TimesAccessed field will be `null`.

Comment: @RichG - that's why I fixed the regex :)